# MYSQL server: Write a query to display cars which was not taken on rent

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

Use Cars and Rentals tables to retrieve records.

**CARS**(*car_id*, car_name, car_type)

**RENTALS**(*rental_id*, cust_id, car_id, pickup_date, km, fare)

```
SELECT c.car_id, c.car_name, c.car_type 
FROM cars as c, rentals as r
WHERE c.car_id=r.car_id and r.pickup_date=null 
ORDER BY c.car_id;
```

I've tried this but output is *NO ROWS SELECTED*

Comment: Use left join rather than antiquated comma join. And do add sample data as text to the question

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `NOT EXISTS` for this query:

```
select c.*
from cars c
where not exists (select 1 from rentals r where r.car_id = c.car_id);
```

That said, your query has multiple errors:

- The comma in the `FROM` clause is very last-century.  Use `JOIN`.
- `= NULL` is *always* going to filter out all rows.  Almost all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL` which is treated as "false".  The correct comparison is `IS NULL`, but I don't think that is needed.
- You can specify equivalent logic using `LEFT JOIN`, but I think `NOT EXISTS` is closer to the statement of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your original intent was to join the two tables and filters on rows that did not match on the right side of the join. This technique is sometimes called an *anti left join*.

Your attempt failed because you need a `left join` rather than an (implicit) `inner join`, and because you did not properly check for nullity (this requires operator `is null`).

The `left join` solution phrases as:

```
select c.*
from cars c
left join rentals r on r.car_id = c.car_id
where r.car_id is null
order by c.car_id
```

Note that I check for nullity on column `car_id` rather than `pickup_date` - any column that is not nullable can do, however I find the intent clearer when using the joining column.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT car_id, car_name, car_type 
FROM cars
WHERE car_id NOT IN (SELECT car_id FROM rentals)
ORDER BY car_id;
```